# Symfony 2 styling / reference locations

Tags: php, apache, symfony, reference

I'm just getting used to Symfony 2 and have been given a project that I have to make changes to. I've a pretty simple problem but can't figure it out.

At the moment when I'm viewing the pages I see them at a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/TheProj/web/myproject/session/start
```

But no images/ styling etc works. Looking in the code all the references are to file locations like:

/js/234234.js

So it thinks it's at the root but it's not. Is this something I change in the Symfony 2 set up or Apache?

UPDATE:

Some more details. This is in a WAMP enviornment. I have tried:

```
app/console assets:install
```

and then

```
app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

To no avail.

Comment: link to the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: THanks, was reading that and trying to make sense on it. No luck so far, it's complete change from what I'm used to.

Comment: In fact, to complete the @YoannCh answer, you need to use console command, but a lot of thing are to check. Does the project use less ? Does less are installed ? Does your vendors are installed ? Does your project need composer, is composer installed ? it's just some questions, a lot of things are to check...

Comment: In your case, i think you should start, by the start [sorry] http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
app/console assets:install
```

and then

```
app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

?

Comment: I didn't, but also have to admit I've no idea what that means. I'm presuming they're console commands?

Comment: You are totally right. You have to go in your project root where there should be some folders such as vendor, src, app. You'll have to type these two commands here. Assets:install exports static resources from bundles to web and assetic:dump dumps your CSS and JS files that have to be dumped resulting in files such as your "234234.js". Consider having a look at [this part of the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) :)

Comment: It's starting to make some sense, thanks for helping out. When I type that I'm getting app not being a recognised command though. Scratch that....just put PHP in front of it and it worked

Comment: Ok...I've done both those commands and am still not getting any styles or JS. Anything else I could be doing wrong? By the way, when I ran those commands it did appear to do things, but viewing the site in my browser is still without styles etc.